# JQuery append li to exist ul

Tags: jquery, html-lists

I searched a lot and made lots of changes, but I still cannot find a solution.

What I want to do is after clicking a button, remove all li in ul and append some other new li in this ul.

HTML is:

```
<ul id = "wordPrediction">
    <li class="nextWord">foot</li>
    <li class="nextWord">hand</li>
 </ul>
```

I first use following code to remove all li:

```
$('#wordPrediction li').each(function(){
    $("#wordPrediction li").fadeOut(500, function(){ 
        $("#wordPrediction li").remove(); 
    });
});
```

Then I try to append all elements in nextWordArray to this ul, I tried:

```
for (var i=0;i<nextWordArray.length;i++){
    $('#wordPrediction').append($("<li class=\"nextWord\">"+nextWordArray[i] +"</li>"));
}
```

But I failed, specifically, when I have nextWordArray = ['actor'], which means my nextWordArray.length = 1. I cannot append successfully.

Comment: When are you trying to append new elements? Just after calling your fadeOut() snippet or what? You should better describe what you mean by `But it doesn't work`??? Just FYI, fadeOut() complete callback is called asynchronously, so if you append elements before the complete callback is fired, using `$("#wordPrediction li").remove();`, you are just removing what you just appended. Instead you could use `$(this).remove();` but you surely have better thing to do to handle your expected behaviour

Comment: Oh god, it works!  when I changed $("#wordPrediction li").remove();  to $(this).remove; and keep rest of codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not seeing what is wrong with the code you have posted, maybe you need to provide more information? Please see [working fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/y3llowjack3t/q342e1yy/)

```
var nextWordArray = ["toe", "finger", "thumb", "nose", "elbow"];
$("#removeListItems").on("click", function(){
    $('#wordPrediction li').each(function(){
    $("#wordPrediction li").fadeOut(500, function(){ 
        $("#wordPrediction li").remove(); 
    });
    });
});


$("#addNewListItems").on("click", function(){
  for (var i=0;i<nextWordArray.length;i++){
      $('#wordPrediction').append($("<li class=\"nextWord\">"+nextWordArray[i] +"</li>"));
  }
});

<ul id = "wordPrediction">
    <li class="nextWord">foot</li>
    <li class="nextWord">hand</li>
 </ul>

 <button id="removeListItems">
 Remove
 </button>

  <button id="addNewListItems">
 Add New
 </button>
```

Comment: Yeah, it works! Maybe I should separate it to two functions.

Comment: @nickyzhi Since the answer has helped you, please accept this as answer and close this thread so that system doesn't treat it as unanswered one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem with your code. Did you put your `for` loop in the `fadeOut` callback, after the `$("#wordPrediction li").remove();` line ?
You need to put your loop after the `remove` else your new elements will get removed by the `remove`.

Here is a working fiddle :

https://jsfiddle.net/eh1snor1/1/

Is this not the expected behavior ?

Comment: Actually I want to remove all of li at first, with a fadeOut effect, and then append the new array into ul. I replaced the $("#wordPrediction li").remove(); with $(this).remove();, then my problem is solved.